# Parsley.js - Do not show total error list bottom of form

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I'd like to avoid showing all of the error messages as a list on the bottom of the form but instead only show each error under the appropriate input box.

Can't seem to figure out how to do it though..

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share here a jsfiddle showing your problem? By default, Parsley should append errors below each field. You may have not installed it properly. Best

Comment: Hey, just saw your reply now.

I don't remember how, but the issue was easily fixed.. I think I was doing something wrong.

Thanks for building this! I use it in every application :)